# Migrate two magento 1 websites on single magento 2 setup with multi website

Tags: magento2, data-migration

We have 2 magento 1 websites each on it's own magento 1 installation, is it possible to migrate them and merge them on same magento 2 installation as multiple website (website A & website B) keeping stores for each of them separate for its own(website A -> store A ; website B -> store B )?

If yes then can we need to do it before migrate or after?